# DropzoneJS upload not starting file upload

Tags: jquery, dropzone

Pretty simple: I've implemented the DropzoneJS like this:

JS:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#my_dropzone', {
  url: 'http://localhost/api/fileupload/',
  paramName: 'file',
  maxFiles: 100,
  maxFilesize: 10,
  method: 'POST',
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  createImageThumbnails: true,
  thumbnailWidth: 120,
  thumbnailHeight: 120,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  acceptedFiles: '.pdf,.doc,.docx',
  accept: function (result, done) {
    console.log(result);
    // $('#arquivos_processo_dropzone_files_area table tbody').append(result);
  },
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="dropzoneholder dropzone-default dropzone-success" id="my_dropzone">
    <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick">
      <h3 class="dropzone-msg-title" Click here to send files.</h3> <span class="dropzone-msg-desc">You can
        send:<br><i>.pdf</i> &nbsp; <i>.doc</i> &nbsp; <i>.docx</i></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I try to send any file it's not starting the POST request as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your accept() function has to call the done callback.

```
accept: function(result, done) {
   // ...
   done();
}
'''
```